# Text Box functions have wrong return type in Windows forms app

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, user-input, return-type

I've recently started learning .NET development. I was trying to make a basic SQL server connect form and I keep running into a wrong return type error for the Text Box functions that accept the username and password for the SQL server connect query.

I was trying to accept user inputs from the Text Boxes and then return their values using a variable.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //These are the variables I'm trying to pass to connect functions
    string User_name = textBox1_TextChanged(sender, e);
    string Pswd = textBox2_TextChanged(sender, e);

    string connection_string = null;
    MySqlConnection conn;
    connection_string = $"server=localhost;database=practice;uid={User_name};pwd={Pswd};";
    conn = new MySqlConnection(connection_string);
    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        MessageBox.Show("Connection Established !");
        conn.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) 
    {
        MessageBox.Show($"Cannot open Connection ! \nErr code : {ex}");
    }
}

//Changed return type from default void to string
public string textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string User_name = textBox1.Text;
    return User_name;
}

public string textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string Pswd = textBox2.Text;
    return Pswd;
}
```

This how the form looks right now.
[image]

The Errors i get are:

1. CS0407 'string Form1.textBox1_TextChanged(object, EventArgs)' has the wrong return type ; File = Form1.Designer.cs ; Line = 85
2. CS0407 'string Form1.textBox2_TextChanged(object, EventArgs)' has the wrong return type ; File = Form1.Designer.cs ; Line = 99

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Those are event methods.  They don't return anything.  Their signature has to match: `public void textBox1_TextChanged(...)`

Comment: You don't need those `TextChanged()` events.  Just retrieve the `.Text` properties directly in the button click handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are trying to get the values from two text boxes (textBox1 and textBox2) to use them in your SQL Server connection string. However, there are some issues with your code.

Event handlers for the **TextChanged** event should return **void**, not **string**. These event handlers are meant to respond to changes in the text boxes and do not need to return values. Instead, you should access the values directly from the text boxes when needed.

You should not call the **TextChanged** *event handlers* explicitly as you are doing here:

`string User_name = textBox1_TextChanged(sender, e);`

**Instead**, you should access the **Text** property of the text boxes directly in your **button1_Click** event handler.

Here's a modified version of your code that addresses these issues:

***C#***

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Get the values from the text boxes
    string User_name = textBox1.Text;
    string Pswd = textBox2.Text;
    string connection_string = null;
    MySqlConnection conn;
    connection_string = $"server=localhost;database=practice;uid={User_name};pwd={Pswd};";
    conn = new MySqlConnection(connection_string);
    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        MessageBox.Show("Connection Established !");
        conn.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) 
    {
        MessageBox.Show($"Cannot open Connection ! \nErr code : {ex}");
    }
}
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // This event handler can remain as it is if you want to perform any specific actions
    // when the text in textBox1 changes.
}
private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // This event handler can remain as it is if you want to perform any specific actions
    // when the text in textBox2 changes.
}
```

In **this code I changed**, the **button1_Click** event handler directly accesses the Text property of **textBox1** and **textBox2** to get the values entered by the user. The **TextChanged** event handlers are left as they are in case you want to perform any specific actions when the text in the text boxes changes.

**If You Found This Useful Please Mark My Answer :D**

Answer (score -1):

### Model - View

In modern programming, there is a tendency to separate your data, and operations on the data (= model), from the way that your data is displayed (= view). This has the advantage, that you can change your model, without having to display your view.

For instance, if you have separate procedures to do the username-password checking, and later you decide not to use a database anymore, but send the data over internet, or maybe simpler, save it in a CSV-file, then you don't have to change the view.

Similarly, if you don't want to use a TextBox for your user name, but a RichTextBox, you'll change the view, but your model doesn't have to change.

Another example: you can reuse your model. For instance, an administrator program where you want to display all user names and passwords in one big Table, may reuse the same model.

And last but not least: it is possible to unit test your model without the windows forms, and you might mock your model, so others can test your user interface.

To connect the model and the view, an adapter class is needed, quite often called the ViewModel.

These three classes are abbreviated as MVVM. If this is all new to you, consider to read some background information about MVVM.

**Back to your problem**

### The model

You are doing way to much in one procedure. This makes the procedure difficult to understand, difficult to maintain and test and impossible to reuse.

You need to divide your code in smaller methods. To improve testability consider to create small classes that have only one goal. Make your code "SOLID" (again, if you are not familiar with the SOLID principle, do some background reading)

First some methods to create an open connection to the database. These methods are easy to understand, easy to test, easy to maintain and change.

```
string ConnectionString => $"server=localhost;database=practice;uid={User_name};pwd={Pswd};";

MySqlConnection DefaultDatabaseConnection => this.CreateOpenDatabaseConnection(this.ConnectionString);

// Returns an open Connection to the database with connectionString
// throws InvalidOperationException if cannot open
MySqlConnection CreateOPenDatabaseConnection(string connectionString)
{
    MySqlConnection dbConnection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);

    // open the database connection. 
    // Throws InvalidOperationException if cannot open        
    dbConnection.Open();
    return dbConnection;
}
catch (Exception ex) 
{
    MessageBox.Show($"Cannot open Connection ! \nErr code : {ex}");
}
```

The method that checks if a provided UserName - Password combination is valid or not.

```
bool IsUserNamePasswordCombinationValid(string userName, string password)
{
    // DbConnection implements IDisposable. So we should use "using"
    using (var dbConnection = this.DefaultDatabaseConnection)
    {
        return this.IsUserNamePasswordCombinationValid(dbConnection,
            string userName, string password);
    }
    // Dispose() will close the database connection
}

SqlCommand CreateSqlCommandCheckUserNamePassword(MySqlConnection connectedDb),
{
   const string parameterUserName = "@UserName";
   const string parameterPassword = "@Password";

   string sqlText = ... 
   // Todo: create sql text that returns 1 if userName / password combination
   // is in the database. user parameterUserName and parameterPassword as
   // parameters in the sqlText

   command.CommandText = sqlText;
   command.Parameters.Add(parameterUserName, userName);
   command.Parameters.Add(parameterPassword, password);
   return command;          
}
```

After all these small methods, usually only one line, we can finally put everything together:

```
bool IsUserNamePasswordCombinationValid(MySqlConnection connectedDb,
     string userName, string password)
{
    // SqlCommand implements IDisposable, so we'll use using
    using (SqlCommand command = this.CreateSqlCommandCheckUserNamePassword(connectedDb)}
    {
        // we expect only one boolean, so we can use ExecuteScalar
        return (bool)command.ExecuteScalar();
    }
}
```

This looks like a lot of methods. Luckily most methods are one-liners. They have only one specific task, nothing else. Their functionality is easy to understand, and easy to test. If changes occur, for instance the connection string, or the SqlText, only one method has to change.

If you plan do reuse this code, consider to put this all in one class, for instance:

```
class UserNamePasswordChecker
{
    public bool IsUserNamePasswordCombinationValid(string userName, string password)
    {
        // TODO: add code as described above.
        // all other methods can be private
    }
```

### The View

Only methods to access your TextBoxes, and a method that shows Ok / Not Ok

```
string DisplayedUserName
{
    get => this.textBoxUserName.Text;
    set => this.textBoxUserName.Text = value;
}

string DisplayedPassword
{
    get => this.textboxPassword.Text;
    set => this.textboxPassword.Text = value;
}

bool DisplayedOk
{
    get => ...
    set => ...
}
```

The latter can show a text box, or an image of a big green checkMark, or a big red Cross. Or maybe you want a MessageBox that informs the operator.

This latter one is a good example of how you can change the view, without having to change the model.

### The ViewModel

Now all we have to do is create an adapter for your model and your view. Note that the event handler to handle clicks on button1 is also viewModel. If you decide that you don't want a button, but a menu item that starts the check, neither the model nor the view should change.

```
// your Button1_Click is renamed to what it does, not who starts it
void CheckUserNamePassword(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var checker = new UserNamePasswordChecker();
    this.DisplayedOk = checker.IsUserNamePasswordOk(
        this.DisplayedUserName, this.displayedPassword);
}
```

### Summary

Because we made our procedures SOLID, and because we separated the Model from the View, all our methods are small ones. Every method has only one specific task. This makes it easy to understand what each method does. It is easy to test this simple functionality. It is easy to change the model, without having to change the view, and vice versa. It is easy to reuse the model, for instance in a program for administrators to list all Usernames and Passwords.

Disadvantage: there are a lot of methods.

The changes are not big if you want to put everything in one big method. This won't improve efficiency a lot; however it will deteriorate readability, not to mention the other advantages.